# Laravel Eloquent lookup tables fill models with single query possible?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

It seems if I have `n` lookups for a table then using eloquent will result in `n` queries to database.  Is there a way to use `with` (or some other function) that uses a `join` under the hood instead of multiple queries?

I have empty models of `Constructor`, `Driver`, and `Engine` along with `Car` that specifies the relationships:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function constructor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Constructor');
    }

    public function engine()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Engine');
    }

    public function driver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Driver');
    }
}
```

Using tinker with sql output:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.4 (PHP 7.4.4 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> DB::listen(function ($query) { dump($query->sql);});
=> null
```

Lazy loading: 1 query per lookup as expected

```
>>> App\Car::find(1)->driver
"select * from `cars` where `cars`.`id` = ? limit 1"
"select * from `drivers` where `drivers`.`id` = ? limit 1"
=> App\Driver {#3940
     id: 1,
     name: "Senna",
     number: 12,
     created_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
     updated_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
   }
```

Using a `with` to fill the related models.  Works as expected but requires 4 queries

```
>>> App\Car::with(['engine','constructor','driver'])->find(1)
"select * from `cars` where `cars`.`id` = ? limit 1"
"select * from `engines` where `engines`.`id` in (1)"
"select * from `constructors` where `constructors`.`id` in (1)"
"select * from `drivers` where `drivers`.`id` in (1)"
=> App\Car {#3941
     id: 1,
     engine_id: 1,
     constructor_id: 1,
     driver_id: 1,
     created_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
     updated_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
     engine: App\Engine {#3956
       id: 1,
       name: "Honda",
       created_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
       updated_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
     },
     constructor: App\Constructor {#3960
       id: 1,
       name: "McLaren",
       created_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
       updated_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
     },
     driver: App\Driver {#3965
       id: 1,
       name: "Senna",
       number: 12,
       created_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
       updated_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
     },
   }
```

Using select and join to perform 1 query, but kinda hacking the Car model to achieve my goal and I can no longer user `$car->driver->name` but instead must use `$car->driver_name`

```
>>> App\Car::where('cars.id', 1)->select(['cars.*','engines.name as engine_name','constructors.name as constructor_name','drivers.name as driver_name'])->join('constructors', 'cars.constructor_id', '=', 'constructors.id')->join('drivers', 'cars.driver_id', '=', 'drivers.id')->join('engines', 'cars.engine_id', '=', 'engines.id')->get()
"select `cars`.*, `engines`.`name` as `engine_name`, `constructors`.`name` as `constructor_name`, `drivers`.`name` as `driver_name` from `cars` inner join `constructors` on `cars`.`constructor_id` = `constructors`.`id` inner join `drivers` on `cars`.`driver_id` = `drivers`.`id` inner join `engines` on `cars`.`engine_id` = `engines`.`id` where `cars`.`id` = ?"
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3940
     all: [
       App\Car {#3942
         id: 1,
         engine_id: 1,
         constructor_id: 1,
         driver_id: 1,
         created_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
         updated_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
         engine_name: "Honda",
         constructor_name: "McLaren",
         driver_name: "Senna",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Is there a better way to handle this?  Obviously caching would help, but that seems more like a bandaid than a proper fix

Comment: App\Car::where('cars.id', 1)->with(['engine:id, name', 'constructor:id, name'.......]) - >first();    You need 4 queries... no matter if you see them or not.

Comment: using `with()` always has to run at least 1 extra query on the related table. You can use join, but that meants you end up with a flat array or object. You can choose to reformat it into an array of objects/array though so it looks like the object/array returned by eloquent

Comment: @nikistag "no matter if you see them or not?" I don't follow.

Comment: @djunehor I don't end up with a flat array/object, as you see I am given a Car model in return of my select query (the last one), but it has the added "psuedo attributes" from my join

Comment: `{
         id: 1,
         engine_id: 1,
         constructor_id: 1,
         driver_id: 1,
         created_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
         updated_at: "2020-05-18 11:59:41",
         engine_name: "Honda",
         constructor_name: "McLaren",
         driver_name: "Senna",
       }` is a flat object compared to an array of arrays eloquent gives. You can no longer user `$car->driver->name` but instead must use `$car->driver_name` because it's a flat object

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden yes an engine type can belong to multiple constructors.  Ferrari can be both a constructor and an engine maker.  Another constructor who does not manufactur engines can use Ferrari engines and if they are not satisfied they could change to say a Renault engine.  isn't the primary difference between `belongsTo` and `hasOne` where the foreign key is?  Is laravel going to reduce the # of queries if I flip those around to perform the lookup `with`?

Comment: @djunehor well yes and no.  Yes I lose the array of arrays, but I can still access other fields of car as I normally would.  The advantage is 1 query for n lookups and having to use the flat attributes vs 1+n lookup queries for eloquent's array of arrays.  This is the gist of what I am asking, is there a way in eloquent to get the normal objects with a single query isntead of 1+n lookup queries?

Comment: As long as you use model relationships, no

Comment: Bummer.  Well if you want to "answer" this question I will accept it